# Reversed axis algorithm issue

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, binary

I'm currently working on an electronic projet and there's a little problem with the joystick values. The values are "correct" but they looks weird.

A classical axis from a joystick usually work (for example left to right).

- Totally left : -128
- Center : 0
- Totally left : +128

But here's what I read from this one :

- Totally left : -0
- Slightly on the left : - 128
- Center : "Random" (never totally zeroed, float between -125 and +125)
- Slightly on the right : + 128
- Totally right : +0

For the moment I'm using the following workaround to get a linear progression from -128 to +128 :

```
if (value > 0)
    value = -(128 - value);
else
    test = 128 + value;
```

The problem is I have to do that on several inputs, 2 axis per joyrstick, 3 joystick per device, 4 total devices so 24 times and I need to need keep a response time under 20ms for the entire operation. And that's freaking cycle consuming !

I can binary manipulate the value.
Here's how I actually center it. Raw dump contains array of 0 and 1 read from the controller I/O

```
for (i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    value |= raw_dump[pos + i] ? (0x80 >> i):0 ;
}
```

Do you have any ideas or good algorithm ? I'm starting to be desesperate and I totally suck on binary manipulation... :'(

Comment: Do you mean, for example, 1 represented as 10000000 instead of 00000001 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like whatever mechanism is sampling the joystick actually returns an *unsigned* byte in the range of 0 .. 255, with 0 at the far left and 255 at the far right.

You can convert that value to the range -128 to 127 with one statement:

```
value = (value & 0xFF) - 128;
```

If `value` is a byte variable, you can shorten that to:

```
value ^= 0x80;
```

That conversion should be very quick on any processor, even a 1MHz 6502.

I'm not sure what your second bit of code is about.  If you could describe what you're trying to accomplish there, I can offer further insight.

Comment: Damn ! You've made my night ! Really have to take a look at the bin operators... mainly developping in C# I've probably never used them outside of school some years ago... That fix the issue and that doesn't consume a lot of cycles ! Thanks !

Comment: In fact I still have got a question, if I remember correctly my school lessons for me the sign was defined by a bit, but here if I get it correctly in fact the 0 is -128, 128 is 0 and 256 is +256 ?

Comment: In a signed 8-bit 2s complement number, bit 7 is the sign bit.  The unsigned 8 bit numbers go from `00000000` to `11111111` binary.  But the signed 2s complement numbers go from `10000000` to `11111111` for -128 to -1, and `00000000` to `01111111` for 0 to 127.  All the XOR did above is shift the unsigned range to the signed range by flipping that upper bit.